# How to pass a parameter in a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF within a WordPress theme.

```
<div class="hero">
    <?php
        $landscape_image_1x = wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_field('landscape_image'), 'hero-landscape-1x' );
        $landscape_image_2x = wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_field('landscape_image'), 'hero-landscape-2x' );
        $portrait_image_1x = wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_field('portrait_image'), 'hero-portrait-1x' );
        $portrait_image_2x = wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_field('portrait_image'), 'hero-portrait-2x' );
        $image_alt = get_post_meta( $hero_landscape, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
    ?>
    <picture>
        <source
            media="(orientation: landscape)" 
            srcset="
                <?= $landscape_image_1x; ?> 1x,
                <?= $landscape_image_2x; ?> 2x"
        >
        <source
            media="(orientation: portrait)" 
            srcset="
                <?= $portrait_image_1x; ?> 1x,
                <?= $portrait_image_2x; ?> 2x"
        >
        <img src="<?= $landscape_image; ?>" alt="<?= $image_alt; ?>">
    </picture>
</div>
```

The first code block works perfectly.

At the moment, I'm repeating a lot of code. All that's changing for each variable is the field name e.g. `landscape_image` and the size parameter e.g. `hero-landscape-1x`.

How within PHP do you pass values when echoing variables? Here's my very wrong way of explaining what I mean.

```
<?php
 $image = wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_field( $field ), $parameter );
 echo $image('landscape_image', 'hero_landscape_1x');
 echo $image('landscape_image', 'hero_landscape_2x');
<?
```

Comment: I's sorry, but I have no idea what you mean here. What problem are you actually trying to solve? Does the posted code (the first code block) work? And you're correct, the second code block is very wrong (since that function returns a string or false, which can't be used as a function) and it doesn't give us any hints of what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: The first code block works perfectly.

At the moment, I'm repeating a lot of code. All that's changing for each variable is the field name e.g. `landscape_image` and the size parameter e.g. `hero-landscape`.

I want to know whether it's possible within PHP to write one variable and then pass the field name and size variable for each variable I echo within the template.

Does that make any more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you’re annoyed with the verbosity of

```
 <?php
        $landscape_image_1x = wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_field('landscape_image'), 'hero-landscape-1x' );
        $landscape_image_2x = wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_field('landscape_image'), 'hero-landscape-2x' );
        $portrait_image_1x = wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_field('portrait_image'), 'hero-portrait-1x' );
        $portrait_image_2x = wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_field('portrait_image'), 'hero-portrait-2x' );
        $image_alt = get_post_meta( $hero_landscape, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
    ?>
```

There are a few ways you could go; I see repetition of `get_field()`, but even more than that I see repetition of `wp_get_attachment_image_url(get_field())`

TBH, aside from the loooong function names, this isn’t a big deal unless you find yourself repeating this block.

So one option is to assign repeated values, such as

```
$landscape = get_field('landscape_image');
$portrait  = get_field('portrait_image');
```

but that doesn’t really help much.

Another idea is to encapsulate getting the url with a function.  Notice that you can eliminate the one-time use variables.

```
function image_url($orientation, $location) {
    return wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_field($orientation), $location );
}
?>

    <picture>
        <source
            media="(orientation: landscape)" 
            srcset="<?= image_url('landscape_image', 'hero-landscape-1x' ?>" 1x,
                <?= image_url('landscape_image','landscape_image_2x') ?> 2x"
        >
```

It’s still kinda wordy, but you have eliminated unnecessary assignments while at the same time remaining descriptive in the view.

If you’re worried about collision with existing function name, you could also make it a closure:

```
$url = function ($orientation, $location) {
    return wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_field($orientation), $location );
}
?>
   <picture>
        <source
            media="(orientation: landscape)" 
            srcset="<?= $url('landscape_image', 'hero-landscape-1x' ?>" 1x,
                <?= $url('landscape_image','landscape_image_2x') ?> 2x"
        >
```